# In Python multiprocesssing, why the `qsize()` of a queue is not 0, but `get_nowait()` produce empty item?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue

I write a python program where I use `multiprocessing` lib to communicate between parent process and child process.

[image]

In this code and the running results, the parent process forks only one child process, waiting for data from parent process. `batch_computing_inputs` is a Queue Object in multiprocessing, where parent process can pass data to child process.

When I execute the `qsize()` in the child process, it produce the size of the queue is 1, which means the queue has item that I could pick out. The item is an image with the size of about 1M~2M in base64 format.

but when I execute `get_nowait()` method, it produce an exception in the `try-catch` code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cuichengyu/github/concurrent_batch_computing/server_app.py", line 45, in batch_computing
    cur_batch_computing_input = batch_computing_inputs.get_nowait()
  File "/home/cuichengyu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 126, in get_nowait
    return self.get(False)
  File "/home/cuichengyu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 107, in get
    raise Empty
_queue.Empty

child process -  1683277465.2352884  finish get inputs data.
```

So, why the size of Queue is 1, but I can not get data from the Queue?

Comment: [qsize is not reliable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.qsize). I do not know if this is the cause, but in any case you should not trust qsize.